# Offered a job without an interview

Tags: interviewing

Just like normal processes. We submitted CV through online jobs search sites. Then we got a response for the receipt of CV. Then the next thing, we received a JOB CONTRACT, which is overwhelming! It just sounds too good to be true. It is a job contract for abroad, particularly UK.  We find it odd because we never gone through any interview. It stated everything, the pay, holiday, and the no. of hours for work. We tried researching for their group because they don't have any website or any sort. The company is called Eston group. We tried searching for their name again in the job site but we couldn't find it anymore. We tried researching about this group but nothing came up for any result. Unlike other companies who responded to our applicatons, they are searchable in google. So I am quite suspicious about this Eston Group because we know that there's a lot of fraud in UK.  I have asked their complete recruitment process but they said, once we arrive in UK then interviews will then be set. What do we do? We didn't sign the contract because it asked for sensitive information like passport #, etc. I hope anyonce could help me about this Eston Group if they are legitimate or not.

Comment: This copy reads just like spam.

Comment: Marking this is a duplicate of [How do I verify that a company offering a job actually exists?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/52246/how-do-i-verify-that-a-company-offering-a-job-actually-exists). The names (Edsor, Eston) of the presumably fake companies even sound similar.

Comment: Maybe I am a little naive, but what risks are you exposing yourself with this kind of fraud? Anyone can provide an article about this kind of fraud?

Comment: @SJuan76 Typically they'll ask applicants to front immigration/passport/paperwork fees after signing the "contract." It can also be a form of identity theft: "*We didn't sign the contract because it asked for sensitive information like passport #, etc.*"

Comment: Who is this "we" you're talking about ?

Comment: The hold reason for this question doesn't really make sense - it is not really company specific.

Answer (score 6):

Dont know anything about whether its a scam or not, but I would never accept a job without an interview. The interview is for your behalf aswell. Ýou need to make sure the workplace is right for you and if the workplace is willing to hire candidates without even talking to them, it doesn't sound like a healthy workplace.

Exceptions exists of course, but are few and far between.

Best guess is that this is too good to be true and is indeed a scam.

Comment: Saves me writing the exact same answer :-) https://companycheck.co.uk doesn't find any company under the name that I would trust enough to give them my passport number. Definitely not legit.

Answer (score 1):

Interview has 2 purposes : make sure the candidate fits the company, and make sure the company fits the candidate.

Of course, when you're desperate for a job, you're more willing to take risks. When you've got the choice, you can be picky.

So, the only case in which you can afford no interview at all, is that the company knows the candidate, and the candidate knows the company. And even like that, an interview may help knowing what is the exact purpose of the recruiting. Imagine a sports megastar recruited by the best team of the continent. Maybe they don't need an interview, as they know well each other. They still will have an interview because they still need to be sure they agree on common goals, and also to agree on details.

You don't know the firm. They don't know you, or at least, you can assume so. You didn't have the opportunity to negociate details. All of this is especially suspicious. Recruiting is a kind of seduction process, you've got to seduce them, and they've got to seduce you(professionally speaking, not romantically, of course). Would you agree to marry a partner that you don't know, and tells you everything is already decided?

Answer (score 0):

I recommended being extremely cautious about "cold calls." If they can't tell me where they got my name and why they think I'm a good candidate for the position,  then as far as I'm concerned they're no better than any other telemarketer.